# SKU item contains unexpected value in subscriptionPeriod field

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, sku

I'm getting several exceptions in production that show me an unexpected value in the subscriptionPeriod field of a SKU details item:

```
when (item.subscriptionPeriod) {
   "P1M" -> { // monthly
      holder.viewBinding.textViewPrice.text = ctx.getString(R.string.title_price_billed_monthly, item.price)
   }
   "P1Y" -> { // annual
      holder.viewBinding.textViewPrice.text = ctx.getString(R.string.title_price_billed_annually, item.price)
   }
   else -> {throw UnexpectedBehavior()}
}
```

In production the UnexpectedBehavior() exception is thrown (this does not happen often).
Given the description of the API here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getSubscriptionPeriod() and since my app only offers yearly and monthly subscriptions; I'm lost.

The variable item is a com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails

Note: I modified the code to log what is stored in the subscriptionPeriod variable; once I have that information I will update this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably coming from malicious users attempting to simulate fake receipts: it happens a lot on Android.

One of the things you'll notice with forged receipts are:

- incorrect prices and currencies. For example, we received a $1 amount for a yearly subscriptions whereas the app was €-only, and the price of the yearly plan was 100€ (~ $120)
- incorrect subscription periods (as you described)

So nothing to worry if you correctly validates your subscriptions' receipts.

If you're not sure on what you should do, I've written an article on the subject: [How to fight fraud in your In-App Subscriptions?](https://www.purchasely.com/blog/how-to-fight-fraud-in-app-subscriptions)